# How can I understand 構成?

Tags: meaning

Ok, I have this word "構成".
If you look in translate it means
"constitution" or "configuration" 
Also "composition" or "organization".

But I am reading a japanese technical document, where this word appears in phrases like
"システム構成”　”基本構成”　or ”ソフトウエア構成” and to me, this sounds more like
"System structure" or "Basic Structure" or "Software Structure"

My question is, is this translation possible? Am I understanding it wrong? 
Somehow "Configuration" sounds really really wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

構成 can mean "configuration" in the sense of "initial set-up procedure" (what you need to do right after or along with the installation), but it also means "structure", "organization" or "how things are constructed". If you believe "structure" fits in the context you're dealing with, then I think it's fine.